# rootViewController is black and shows no content

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, appdelegate

My first VC called StartViewController is just black when launch (should be yellow). Can anyone help me??

This is my AppDelegate:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  var window: UIWindow?

  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    //MARK: Start VC
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: StartViewController())
    navController.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    window?.rootViewController = navController
    window?.isOpaque = true
    return true
  }
}
```

This is my StartViewController Class:

```
import UIKit 
class StartViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var btn: UIButton!    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("HELLO WORLD")
    }
}
```

This is how my Storyboard looks like (added afterwards):

[image: storyboard screenshot]

Thanks for any help! If you need to see other classes or stuff please ask! :)

Comment: Is this a new project? The app delegate `window` is no used for anything in iOS 13 and iOS 14, so your code does nothing.

Comment: Its an old project, but just started working at it again (new iOS). How can I fix it? Thank you!

Comment: OK, in that case it should be fine. If you have no scene delegate, you can live without one. That said, there is some stuff that works better, esp if you are not backward beyond iOS 13, if you use a modern template with a scene delegate (and then your code would go there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't initialize a view controller that's in a storyboard like `StartViewController()`. So this doesn't work:

```
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: StartViewController())
```

Instead, you need to use the `instantiateViewController` method. Make sure to also set the "Storyboard ID" in the storyboard for your view controller.

[image: Set the storyboard ID]

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourViewControllerID")
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
```