# Initial screen on iOS simulator is black

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

I have UIViewController that i created programmatically. This is the code. Even after setting my SignUpViewController background to white. I am getting black screen on launch

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        startWindowLoad()
        return true
    }

//extension with the starter function 
extension AppDelegate {
    func startWindowLoad () {
        let startView = SignUpViewController()
        let navView = UINavigationController()
        navView.pushViewController(startView, animated: true )
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        window?.rootViewController = startView
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [rootViewController is black and shows no content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67611263/rootviewcontroller-is-black-and-shows-no-content)

Comment: Not using storyBoard at all so does not help

Comment: Is that a SceneDelegate issue?

Comment: Did your project having scenedelegate file..

Comment: yes. it has scenedelegate file

Answer (score 1):

In a modern app, the app delegate window is not used. You need to use the scene delegate window. Move all the code into the scene delegate.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because your app is starting with `LaunchScreen`

Goto `Info.plist` and
change `Launch screen interface file base name` to `Main`